# Relative positioned divs height added up in IE6 before the negative top

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, positioning

I have the following

```
<div id=A style='height: 120px;'>
  <div id=B style='height: 100px;'>
    <div id=D style='height:  60px; top 0px; position: relative;'>Stuff D</div>
    <div id=E style='height:  80px; top: -40px; position: relative;'>Stuff E</div>
  </div>
  <div id=C style='height:  20px;'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

In browsers other than IE6, this works fine.  However, IE6 adds the heights of D & E to 140 and forces B to become 140 which pushes down C by 40. However, the top of E is rendered 40px overlapping D as it should.  It's just the box for B becomes the 140 high only in IE6.

What can I do with the CSS/HTML to make IE6 behave without affecting other browsers which get it and keep B at 100px?

Comment: <!--[if IE 6]>
<style>#b{height: 100px !important;}</style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Sounds like that might work.  Lemme try.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that margin-top: -??px; will do the same thing as just top: -??px does.  Thanks for the assistance.  I will be trying the overflow: hidden and the !important, because they sound interesting.

Comment: If you can do it without negative margins, it'll probably make your life easier.  They can create some pretty nasty layout bugs.

Comment: To combat another bug (too much to go into now) I could not position the images divs "absolute"ly so I had to do "position:relative" and a negative top (well margin-top now) value to get them to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fact that the heights are added up beforehand that's messing you up---all browsers do this. It's the fact that IE 6 has a different idea of what to do when the `height` of `#B`'s content exceeds `100px`. Since you know the height you want for `#B`, you can add `overflow: hidden` to the existing style.

```
<div id="B" style="height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
```